# File.Create and File.OpenRead and IOException

Tags: c#, ioexception

I need to read a file that is opened for writing in other part of the program

```
const string fileName = "file.bin";
FileStream create = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
FileStream openRead = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The last line raises IOException:

```
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"
```

Please help properly configure File.Open parameters.

Comment: make sure the file is closed before reading

Comment: if you have it opened in another part of **your** application then just refactor this to use it in a single-instance/service so you only have to open it once

Comment: No. I need read from file is opened for writing. Windows must allow this.

Comment: @Alex : Try changing FileShare.Read as FileShare.ReadWrite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `FileShare` parameter to `FileShare.ReadWrite` in both statement:

```
FileStream create = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileStream openRead = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

`ReadWrite` flag description from MSDN:

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading or writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Reniuz's answer, you can do this :

```
FileStream create = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
FileStream openRead = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Notice `FileShare.Read` for the first FileStream for write access. The write stream allows other streams to read it. It doesn't seem safe to set `FileShare.ReadWrite` in the writer stream.

The second stream for read access effectively need to set `FileShare.ReadWrite` because the parameter FileShare defines the permissions for other streams. If you set only `FileShare.Read` while another stream is already open for write, the reader stream simply cannot fulfill the `FileShare.Read` permission (which implicitly says the stream cannot be written by another stream).

I think there is a natural confusion between the two parameters FileAccess and FileShare. The first is basically the permission of the stream you create, the second is for any other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file first with the .Close() method.

Comment: No. I need read from file is opened for writing. Windows must allow this.

Answer (score 0):

The first stream is going to write to the file whereas the second one permits reading only

```csharp
FileStream create = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, **FileAccess.Write**, FileShare.Read);
FileStream openRead = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, **FileShare.Read**);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileShare.ReadWrite` for that:

```
 const string fileName = "file.bin";
    FileStream create = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
    FileStream openRead = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```